# Dynamic join to return all current and past data based on date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transactional sales table.

I'm using something like this to get sales, customers, and orders for the given month and year:

```
SELECT
  month(trans_date) as 'trans_month', 
  year(trans_date) as 'trans_year',
  sum(net_sales) as 'net_sales',
  count(distinct(customer_id)) as 'customers',
  count(distinct(order_id)) as 'orders'
FROM 
    sales_trans_tbl
GROUP BY
  trans_year,
  trans_month
```

The output is this:

| trans_month | trans_year | net_sales | customers | orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 2021 | $452,212 | 85 | 123 |
| Feb | 2021 | $312,484 | 98 | 223 |
| Mar | 2021 | $112,584 | 23 | 444 |

Does a dynamic `JOIN` exist that would take a table of unique orders by day, and join to the tale shown above on my month and year, and return all current and previous unique orders (`lifetime_orders`)?

The alternative which sounds completely wrong is creating a subquery for each month in the desired date range. Desired output would be shown below, where lifetime_orders now in Jan 2021 means all orders in January 2021 and backwards in time, as far as the data goes.

| trans_month | trans_year | net_sales | customers | orders | lifetime_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 2021 | $452,212 | 85 | 123 | 987 |
| Feb | 2021 | $312,484 | 98 | 223 | 878 |
| Mar | 2021 | $112,584 | 23 | 444 | 1,023 |

Comment: What given month and year?  What does `JOIN` have to do with filtering data?  Sample data as well as desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited for clarity.

Comment: what's the structure of the "table of unique orders by day"? also how come lifetime_orders decrease from 987 to 878 in the desired results? shouldn't it be always growing?

Comment: @umberto-petrov its lifetime orders only for the customers who purchased in that month. Structure of the orders data would be order # and day.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell w/o the data, but I think it's possible to do it via "dynamic join", but it would interfere with the calculation of the `net_sales` column

```sql
SELECT
  month(s.trans_date) as 'trans_month', 
  year(s.trans_date) as 'trans_year',
  sum(s.net_sales) as 'net_sales', -- will cause this value to be wrong
  count(distinct(s.customer_id)) as 'customers',
  count(distinct(s.order_id)) as 'orders',
  count(distinct(o.order_id)) as 'lifetime_orders'
FROM sales_trans_tbl s
  LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON o.trans_date <= LAST_DAY(s.trans_date)       
WHERE o.customer_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
    FROM sales_trans_tbl
    WHERE month(trans_date) = month(s.trans_date)
      AND year(trans_date) = year(s.trans_date)
  )     
GROUP BY
  trans_year,
  trans_month
```

May be something like that --

```sql
SELECT
  month(trans_date) as 'trans_month', 
  year(trans_date) as 'trans_year',
  sum(net_sales) as 'net_sales',
  count(distinct(customer_id)) as 'customers',
  count(distinct(order_id)) as 'orders',
  (
    SELECT COUNT(o.order_id)
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.trans_date <= LAST_DAY(s.trans_date)
      AND o.customer_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
        FROM sales_trans_tbl
        WHERE month(trans_date) = month(s.trans_date)
          AND year(trans_date) = year(s.trans_date)
      )
  ) as 'lifetime_orders'
FROM 
    sales_trans_tbl s
GROUP BY
  trans_year,
  trans_month
```

It assumes your orders table has customer ids in it.